# What are the general steps to recreate expired push certificate profile?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I get nervous when I dive too deep into certificates, identifiers, and profiles in iOS. I have an expired distribution push provisioning profile. It expired and I use parse as my push notifications server. I think what I need to do is

-Go to Apple Dev Center
-Create a new provisioning profile with same app id
-Create a new cert signing request and p12?
-Upload p12 to parse?
-Use new provisioning profile and submit app to app store

(I need to update the app anyway)

Is this how I should go about it? If not, what are the general steps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Keychain Access Application on your computer. On the top menu, go to

```
Keychain Access --> Certificate Assistant --> Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority
```

Enter your email address (the same one you used for your Apple Developer Program) and choose Saved to disk option. Give the new file a name and save wherever you want the .certSigningRequest file.

Afterwards log in into your Apple Developer account and navigate to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section. Under the Certificates section choose Production. Select your App ID and click continue twice. When it prompts you to upload a file, upload the recently requested .certSigningRequest file and click generate. Then download the .cer (certificate) file. Double click the .cer file to open it and store it in the keychain.

Once again, go to Keychain Access Application. Under the certificates category select your newly created certificate, right click the certificate and select Export "Apple Production IOS Push Services: Your App ID". Save this file in the .p12 (Personal Information Exchange) format.

Now, go to your Parse app. Under settings select the Push option. In the Apple Push Certificates section, optionally delete your previous expired certificate and choose select your certificate and upload the .p12 file.